# Postgresql only select letters from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

So I have this column which contains the street address and the house number, they are both kept in the same column.

Eg: Boulevard 123

Now I want to separate the letters from the numbers so I get "Boulevard" and "123" separately trough a select statement.

How can I do this, using reg expressions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be returned for `Boulevard 123 South`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the street name with one select statement and the house number trough another select statement

Comment: And what about the `South` part? Is that a third element? Or does it belong to the number? Or to the first part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is by using [`regexp_split_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html) to split the value by the space:

```
SELECT address_arr[1] AS streer_name, address_arr[2] AS street_number
FROM   (SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRY(address, ' ') AS address_arr
        FROM   my_table) t
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

```
select 
    substring(address from '\d+') as street_number, 
    substring(address from '[a-zA-Z\s]+') as street_name 
from addresses
```